# How can I get a list of files and folders in shell folders like shell:Desktop using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have tried the code below, but it just returns literally ONLY the files and folders in my desktop folder. Whereas when you open shell:Desktop in File Explorer you get the same files PLUS all the drive letters and few other shell folders like "This PC" and Libraries.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory));
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in di.GetDirectories())
    Console.WriteLine(subdir.FullName);
```

Comment: Use [`Environment.GetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-6.0) and pass a [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-7.0) to it. e.g. `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolders.Desktop)`.

Comment: @Jesse. Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my question to explain how this is missing some special shell folders that I would also like to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the Shell32 library.

In the Solution Explorer, right-click on your project, choose "Add Reference". Then under "COM", check the "Microsoft Shell" item and click OK.

[image]

You can then use the types from that library.

```
Shell shell = new Shell();
Folder desktop = shell.NameSpace(Shell32.ShellSpecialFolderConstants.ssfDESKTOP);

foreach(ShellFolderItem folderItem in desktop.Items())
{
    Console.WriteLine(folderItem.Type + ": " + folderItem.Name);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. My upvote will count when I get enough rep points. Is there any link to the documentation for the Shell32 classes used here?

Comment: @IndySingh You can find the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/objects

Comment: @IndySingh Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa via P/Invoke to retrieve an Icon for the item

Comment: Amazing, you have answered a question that was in my mind before I even asked it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
        foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
        {
            //All files
            Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
        }


        foreach (DirectoryInfo didet in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            //All directories
            Console.WriteLine(didet.FullName);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my question to explain how this is missing some special shell folders that I would also like to see.